# Why are ions in a mass spectrometer accelerated through electric plates?

Tags: atoms, mass-spectrometry, magnetism, electricity

I was reading an article on the AP Chemistry course in Khan Academy about mass spectrometry, which had this:

> ... ions are then accelerated through electric plates and subsequently deflected by a magnetic field

My question is, why do the ions need to be accelerated? Why can they not move without acceleration?

Comment: Ions need to reach the detector, not just dwell in ionization unit. Plus there are numerous analyzers such as [ToF-MS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-flight_mass_spectrometry) that utilize velocity of accelerated ions.

Comment: @andselisk as [porphyrin points out](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/168340/16035) thermal velocity already guarantees non-dwelling; it's *mass resolution* that drives the need for a well-defined and carefully controlled acceleration. There are no mass analyzers that don't use velocity, be it free motion in a vacuum or diffusion in a gas, liquid, gel, or other medium.

Comment: People are not generally mind-readers, so it is difficult sometimes to understand where the confusion that leads to a question lies. In this case you ask "why can they not move without acceleration?" Ions in a gas do move without needing to accelerate them with an external potential source. The reason for the plates has to do with separating different ions. If you take a gas consisting of a mixture of different types of molecules, how to know which are there (without using chemical reactions)?

Comment: @BuckThorn so if I edit my question to remove the part where I ask why they can't move with acceleration, and just keep the first question, can my question be considered for reopening?

Comment: The use of plates (and the associated electric and magnetic fields) to accelerate and deflect charged particles is what characterizes mass spectrometry as a mass determination tool. Your question is a bit like asking, "why do we need gravity to measure the mass of an object with a balance?" There are in fact other ways to determine mass, it just happens that mass spec uses magnetic and electric fields in a clever way to provide us with a powerful tool. There are other ways of measuring average molecular mass of a gas, for instance by measuring effusion  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effusion

Comment: I will leave it to votes for the question to be opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field helps capture almost all of the ions and accelerates them towards the detector. These ions initially have a statistical distribution of velocities (due to Boltzmann/thermal distribution plus inhomogeneities in the source) and this can lead to wide mass peaks. Accelerating the ions (with the same charge $z$) gives them approximately the same kinetic energy, independent of mass, as $KE=eV=(1/2)mv^2$ where $V$ is the acceleration voltage (typically a few thousand volts) and $v$ the velocity on leaving the accelerating plate. The heavier ions move more slowly than lighter ones and thus  become separated in proportion to $m/z$ while moving along the drift tube. The speed is now such that the initial distribution becomes a smaller fraction of the kinetic energy than it was and is therefore less important. When entering the magnetic field they are deflected by differing amounts (i.e. follow a different radius) and so strike the detector in different places. The change in radius $\delta r$, and so splitting of mass peaks, is proportional to $\sqrt{V}$.

Comment: Just a caveat: though perhaps not as prevalent in a typical analytical lab, there are also spherical electrostatic and electric quadrupole mass spectrometers that don't use magnetic fields; they disperse as $\Delta E / E$ rather than $\Delta p / p$ for magnetic dispersion.

Comment: @Uhoh and of course also time of flight